# extract xml tag value from file where file name has spaces

Tags: ksh, xml

I have a file 'EXXARS - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf'

file data:

```
<header>
 <prop-group name="ora_reconstruction">
    <prop prop-type="TemplateCode">XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS</prop>
    <prop prop-type="extractorVersion">10.1.3.4.2_1.5</prop>
 </prop-group>
```

I need extract the value between and result: I need this value in the variable XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_ES.

I have coomand which is not working

```
filename='ES - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf'
sed -n 's:.*<prop prop-type="TemplateCode">\(.*\)</prop>.*:\1:p' filename > ${LOBCODE}
echo " --> ${LOBCODE}"
```

Comment: I'm assuming there's more to the `.xlf` file than just what you have there, correct? Otherwise, it's malformed XML and the tag isn't really appropriate.

Comment: yes,,,I gave just frist 10 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the XML file is well formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<header>
  <prop-group name="ora_reconstruction">
    <prop prop-type="TemplateCode">XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS</prop>
    <prop prop-type="extractorVersion">10.1.3.4.2_1.5</prop>
  </prop-group>
</header>
```

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlfile='ES - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf'
LOBCODE=$( xml sel -t -v '//prop[@prop-type="TemplateCode"]' "$xmlfile" )
```

This uses XMLStarlet to extract the value of the `prop` node whose `prop-type` attribute is `TemplateCode`. The variable `LOBCODE` will get the value `XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS` with the above XML.

XMLStarlet may sometimes be installed as `xmlstarlet` rather than as `xml`.

---

There are two issues with your code:

1. You redirect the output of the `sed` command to a file whose name is given by `$LOBCODE`.  If `$LOBCODE` is empty, then this redirection will fail. What I assume you wanted to do was to assign the output of `sed` to the variable `LOBCODE`.  This is done with a command substitution as I've shown above.  Note that `sed` is a poor choice of tool for parsing XML data.
2. You instruct `sed` to work with a file called `filename`.  To have `sed` work on the *value of the variable* `filename` you will need to use `$` in front of the variable name.  Also, since the filename has spaces in it, you need to double quote the variable expansion (you should *always* do this, regardless).  Hence you should use `"$filename"` (I've used a more descriptive variable name in my code above).

Answer (score 0):

@Kusalananda's answer is excellent, but if you have `xmllint` instead, you can use this:

```
filename='ES - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf'
LOBCODE=$(xmllint --xpath "header/prop-group[@name='ora_reconstruction']/prop[@prop-type='TemplateCode']/text()" "$filename")
```

Notes:

- I used the full path specification in case you only want the `prop-group` with the "ora-reconstruction" attribute. @Kusalananda's method assumes you want any `prop` element with an attribute of "TemplateCode": which method is preferable depends on your data.
- `text()` returns just the text inside the `prop` element (otherwise, `xmllint` returns the surrounding element as well.)

Example run of the important part:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "header/prop-group[@name='ora_reconstruction']/prop[@proptype='TemplateCode']/text()" "ES - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf"
XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS
```

Comment: we cannot install the upgraded switch of xmllint  and XMLStarlet.  due to limitation. can you please to extract using the string? Oracle suggests the same

Answer (score -2):

```
$ cat test.xml
<header>
 <prop-group name="ora_reconstruction">
    <prop prop-type="TemplateCode">XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS</prop>
    <prop prop-type="extractorVersion">10.1.3.4.2_1.5</prop>
 </prop-group>

$ awk -F"[<>]" '/TemplateCode/{print $3;exit}' test.xml
XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS
```

Comment: Using `awk` and friends for XML processing is almost always a bad idea, because they don't know anything about the structure of the data and are incredibly brittle. For example, if "TemplateCode" shows up in some other (non-`prop` related) context in the XML file before the one you're interested in, you'll end up with erroneous results. There are enough common tools that know about XML nowadays!

Comment: we cannot install the upgraded switch of xmllint and XMLStarlet. due to limitation. can you please to extract using the string? Oracle suggests the same